# gevent: composing greenlets in series

Tags: python, gevent, finagle

In Twitter's `Finagle`, `map` and `flatMap` can be used to chain multiple asynchronous operations. For example, a simple web scraper might do something like,

```
downloadURL(url)                     // download a web page
  .flatMap(extractProducts)          // extract individual products for sale on it
  .foreach(saveToDatabase)           // save output to a database
```

I would like to do something very similar using `gevent` in Python, but I'm not sure how to do so. `Greenlet.link` seems to be a start, but it doesn't give me access to the `Greenlet` containing the final result (as far as I can tell).

How do I mimic `Finagle`'s `map` and `flatMap` operations with `gevent.Greenlet`?

Comment: Maybe you should use a Queue instead?

Answer (score 3):

gevent isn't designed for "asynchronous" programming (stacking callbacks, *in this context*), but for concurrent programming.

The description on gevent's page makes it very clear:

> gevent is a coroutine-based Python networking library that uses greenlet to provide a high-level synchronous API on top of the libevent event loop.

What you're looking for is [`twisted`](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) (be warned, though, that's not the most "beginner-friendly" framework there is).